# Huge binary matrix (logical AND on array of bitsets) Java performance

Tags: java, arrays, performance, binary-data, bitset

We have a java service that computes some logical operations on a huge binary matrix (10 000 x 10 000). This matrix is array of bitsets. The most important operation is an intersection (logical AND) betwen a given bitset and each bitset in the array. We are using OpenBitset and it shows quite good results (at least better than java.util.BitSet). Data sparsity is moderate (could be many 0 or 1 in a row), bitset size is fixed.

The most important thing for us is fast response times (for now it's ~0.05 sec), so we would like to find ways for further improvements as the matrix and the quantity of requests are growing. There could be some algebraic methods or faster libraries for that.

We tried to use [javaewah](http://code.google.com/p/javaewah/), but this library performed operations 10x times slower comparing to OpenBitset. There is comparision on the project's page, that shows that other bitset-compression libraries slower than Java BitSet.

Could you suggest some other methods or new ideas?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by what operation you're trying to do. Are you creating a 100 million bit array with the results? Could you post some sample code?

Comment: Do you have a limit on the width of the bit sets? If not, what is the distribution of the widths?

Comment: Nick, If I will be more preciese, there is array of 7 000 bitsets, each bitset consist of 15 000 bits. So we have a binary matrix consisting of 7 000 rows and 15 000 columns. The operation I'm trying to discuss  is to intesect an ad-hoc bitset to each of 7 000 bitsets.

Comment: Patricia, the width (size) of the bitset is set during initialization, it's correct to say the each bitset has the same width of 15 000 bits.

Comment: it is necessary to use java for such things? C++ or C will improve speed significally, i think.

Answer (score 1):

In my recent blog I discussed a "yet another" bitset implementation - with source code. Maybe you want to give it a try: http://www.censhare.com/en/aktuelles/censhare-labs/yet-another-compressed-bitset

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using client-server solution, [pilosa](https://github.com/pilosa/java-pilosa) would be perfect for your use case.

- bindings for java,python,go
- groupBy support
- time range support
- huge matrix support
- uses high-performance roaringbitmap
- scales horizontally
- helm chart https://github.com/pilosa/helm